# How to handle launch application confirm box with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to change my view when the browser tab is not focused. I used `window.onblur` event to handle this situation but there is one use case that I want to handle.

When the launch application confirm box appears window fires blur event but the user still is in the page so that i don't want to change the view on page. I should change the view only when the user switch different window or tab.

**Example for Launch Application Confirm Box**

[image]

I've searched for launch application confirm's events and also object in window, navigator and document objects but i did not find any related object, function or event. Also I've searched mdn for specific API to achieve this, but I could not find any solution to this problem.

If you know any documentation about launch confirm box please share with. I would appreciate for any help that will solve my use case with another point of view.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by handling `visibilitychange` event instead of `blur` as below.

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
    //Change your view here
});
```

More details on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API). Please note there are browser specific events too.

```
"visibilitychange"
"msvisibilitychange"
"webkitvisibilitychange"
```

In case, you want to handle the situation when user clicks out of browser keeping the site visible, as well. Handle `blur` event instead.

But now, 'launch application pop-up' which also blurs the window, to be handled specifically. It does not fire any event to handle

we can have a quick work around to handle it.
The idea is based on below 2 behaviors,

1. The link that fires this popup, will not start with http or https. for example, zoom uses url that starts with `zoommtg://` to launch native application.
2. `onclick` events fired before `onblur` event.

Hence, Introducing a flag on `click` event, will help us handle this popup.

```js
changeViewFlag=true;

window.onblur=function(event){
        if(changeViewFlag==true)
        {
            //Change your view here
        } 
        changeViewFlag=true;
    }

window.onclick=function(event){
        if(event.target.href!=null &&
           event.target.href.split("://").length>1 &&
           ["http","https"].indexOf(event.target.href.split("://")[0])==-1)
           {
             changeViewFlag=false;
           }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Visibility change event will cover the main functionality but there is an exceptional case. If the user uses multiple monitors or small browser window then browser will not fire visibility change event. I should cover this case as well.

Comment: @OzanBatuhanCeylan I have updated the answer. please check.

Comment: This work around can solve the issue but in real world application there is too hard to manage this events in application wide. So that i need more encapsulated solution.